# .htaccess domain forwarding issue

Tags: .htaccess, dns, redirect, forwarding

The following code in the .htaccess file is supposed to, among others I guess, redirect the secondary domains towards the main domain:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header unset Last-Modified
</ifModule>
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain1.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain1.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain2.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain2.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain3.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain3.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain4.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain4.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain5.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain5.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain6.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain6.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain7.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain7.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

Unfortunately if I type www.secondaryDomain.com/index.html or www.secondaryDomain.com/directory it is not redirected towards the main domain. 
What has been done wrong in the .htacess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

This rewrites **only** URLs ending in / or nothing at all. You should use something like:

```
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com$1" [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Which redirects and preserves all path-info.

Comment: Thanks @Laas, I think I'm getting closer; now if I type www.secondarydomain.com/index.html it seems to try to redirect to mainDomain.comindex.html. If I type www.secondaryDomain.com/directory I'm not redirected, though.

Comment: @Laas, I've used 'RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]'and it redirects correctly for "www.secondaryDomain.com/index.html . So half of the issue is solved, thanks!

Comment: Ahah! The "RewriteBase /" snatched the slash from the beginning of the URL, so yes, your solution is correct.

Comment: One thing to try is to move all of this domain-related rewrites up, just below the line `RewriteEngine On`, so that all redirects are done before any other rewriting takes place, which makes sense to me. Does this /directory actually exist? One of the rules checks for existance and rewrites all non-existant queries to /index.php (and stopping all other rewrites)

Comment: Thanks, I've moved all the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain7.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain7.com$
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com$1" [R=301,L,QSA]`

Comment: Yes, the directory exists. I've moved all the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^secondaryDomain7.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.secondaryDomain7.com$
RewriteRule (.*) "http\:\/\/mainDomain\.com$1" [R=301,L,QSA]` - if this is what you meant, but it doesn't help me any further. Thank you though for helping me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://mainDomain.com/ [L]
</IfModule>
```

I am assuming that this .htaccess file is for secondarydomain.com ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I don't know if the .htaccess file is for the secondary domain, it is located on the server on which the website connected to these domains is. I have tried to make the change you've suggested and it doesn't help me. Thanks for trying to help, though!

Comment: tried it, thanks again but it doesn't work; if I type www.secondarydomain.com/index.html it seems to try to redirect to mainDomain.comindex.html (I get the 'Server not found'error). If I type www.secondaryDomain.com/directory I'm not redirected, and I don't know where to go from there. Thanks a lot for trying to help!